# React Native run-ios with .xcworkspace

Tags: ios, react-native

```
react-native run-ios --project-path 'ios/myProject.xcworkspace' --simulator=\"iPhone 8 Plus\"
```

Specifying the project path to the .xcworkspace file fails `Could not find Xcode project files in ios folder`

I've seen that this is an item proposed in the `React Native` roadmap: https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/specifying-the-xcworkspace-to-be-used-in-the-command-line-options

Is there a way (right now) to use `Cocoapods` with `React Native` and run with the command line? I'm aware that it works perfectly fine when building through xcode.

Thanks

Comment: `react-native run-ios` will run your `.xcworkspace` file. There's no need for the `--project-path` flag. I'm a little confused, do you have multiple xcworkspace files?

Comment: No I don't have multiple xcworkspaces, but run-ios is running xcodeproj not xcworkspace for me..

Comment: Have the same issue here

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to run it without `--project-path`. You would use `--project-path` to specify `ios` (the folder containing both `.xcworkspace` and `.xcodeproj`. Then the CLI will [automatically pick](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/local-cli/runIOS/findXcodeProject.js) `.xcworkspace` if it exists, otherwise it will pick `.xcodeproj`. When you start you should get a message like this:

> Found Xcode workspace myProject.xcworkspace

Comment: I switched to a new laptop yesterday running OSX Mojave. I set up my toolchain. Everything seems to be in order. I pulled my branch from github and launched with `react-native run-ios` as usual. The launcher executed the `xcodeproj` file, not `xcworkspace`. However, launching in Xcode, it runs as intended.

Comment: @MikeS. same for me - Do you remember the solution?

Comment: @chenop This hasn't been an issue for me since that time. Currently in my `package.json`, I have 
`"compile-ios": "react-native run-ios --no-packager --simulator=\"iPhone 11\"",
    "ios": "yarn compile-ios & yarn start",`
I then run `yarn ios`. That works as intended.